# Only first button with ID responds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

For an assignment i have to make a page that has 3 questions with each 3 answers in the form of a button.
When the button is clicked, the color of it will change depending if the answer is correct or not.

I can get the Jquery to work, but it only seems to apply to the first correct and wrong button i have.

like, the first correct answer is 1A, it will change, but no other correct answer will respond, even if they are clicked first, same for the wrong answers, only 1B will react.

Question 1
   answer 1A
   answer 1B
   answer 1C

Question 2
   answer 2A
   answer 2B
   answer 2C

Question 3
   answer 3A
   answer 3B
   answer 3C

-edit-
Ok i get it, cant re-use ID's..

HTML

### Doe mee aan onze quiz!

```
        <h4>Wat is de naam van Master Chief?</h4>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonjuist">John-117</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">Douglas-092</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">James-016</button>

        <h4>Hoeveel kandidaten zijn er voor het SPartan-II project?</h4>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">300</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonjuist">150</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">75</button>

        <h4>Waar wordt Master Chief gevonden?</h4>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">Reach</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonfout">Harvest</button>
        <button class="buttons" id="buttonjuist">Eridanus</button>
```

CSS

```
.buttons{ 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:small;
    background-color:blue;
    width:200px;
    }
```

Jquery

```
$("#buttonjuist").on('click', function()     
        {      
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});     
        });

$("#buttonfout").on('click', function()     
        {      
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});     
        });
```

Comment: IDs must be unique! Class can be re used as many times as you like

Comment: IDs are supposed to be uniue: only one should exist on the page.

Comment: @Augusto — That's not a best practise, it is a requirement of the language.

Comment: But when i try to add 2 classes to the button, it says one has already been added to the button tag

Comment: @Vahx `class="buttons buttonjuist"`

Comment: `$('button.buttons[id="buttonjuist"]').on('click', function()` and `$('button.buttons[id="buttonfout"]').on('click', function()` should work in your scenario even though it is not right to re-use IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, you have two classes `buttonjuist` (correct answer) and `buttonfout` (wrong answer). When you change your buttons to

```
<button class="buttons buttonjuist">John-117</button>
<button class="buttons buttonfout">Douglas-092</button>
```

and the jQuery to

```
$(".buttonjuist").on('click', function()     
        {      
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});     
        });

$(".buttonfout").on('click', function()     
        {      
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});     
        });
```

it will work as expected.

Full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGjX7/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `id` attribute, use `class`.

Otherwise, only the first one will be selected.

Answer (score 2):

As it's been said many times already, id's should be unique. If for some reason you feel like going against everyone's advice and stick to id's (don't!), this will work:

```
$('button[id=buttonfout]')
```

But yeah, use classes and do something like :

```
$('button.buttonfout')
```

It's a much better practice.